# Can I list installed applications from a Bash script?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, script, automation

When we image machines we install a list of applications.

At the end, we want to check that each has indeed been successfully installed.

In our shell script, how can we get a list of all installed applications so that we can compare it with our list of required apps?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: sorry, im looking for a script to see if I can pull a list in terminal that can check to see if certain applications were installed rather than going into applications and looking one by one

Comment: As written, it's still too broad.  For example, you can issue the command `sudo find / -name *.app` to find all Apps on any system, however, that doesn't include binaries (like `ffmpeg`) that may have been downloaded manually.  What specifically, are you looking to do?

Comment: When we image machines we install a list of application, some are inhouse some are public such as Chrome
At the end of the imaging process we have to manually see if all the application installed successfully

What im hoping for is a script that can list the applications and verify if it was installed or not to save time

Comment: How are you doing this now?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways via the command line to look to see if an Application is installed:

#### View the Applications Directory

- To list all Applications installed system wide:

  ```
    $ ls /Applications
  ```
- To list Applications installed by/for a specific user:

  ```
    $ ls /Users/<username>/Applications
  ```

#### Query `system_profiler`

The following command will list every single Application installed on the system that's in the Applications database:

```
$ system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType
```

It lists *everything* including obscure apps/utilities installed by Apple (or 3rd parties) that was included with the macOS installation.  Using `grep` we can limit it to a particular application.

```
$ system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType | grep -i Excel
    Microsoft Excel:
      Location: /Applications/Microsoft Excel.app
```

The caveat with these is that it must have been "properly" installed and registered with the system.  If you happen to download a binary directly from a website (`ffmpeg` is an excellent example), it won't show up using any of these methods.

#### Use `which` or `type`

For binaries that weren't installed, but rather just downloaded or copied onto a system and *assuming they are in the path*, you can use the command `which` or `type`

```
$ which ffmpeg
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg

$ type ffmpeg
ffmpeg is /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```